# cant put div below everything on page

Tags: html, css, position, footer

my footer wont go to the bottom below everything. i dont want it fixed to the bottom of the browser
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13722201/Dorset%20Designs/home.html

Comment: but i want you to scroll down to see it

Comment: Well it's missing a close html tag :\ why is the footer position absolute?

Comment: You have to change a lot. As you have applied position fixed to "main"  div.

Comment: position:fixed makes main div out of stack, and footer thinks that there is nothing after <div id="title">. You should reorganize way of your html/css

Comment: without downloading it and messing with it, I would say that you need to setup 3 divs, header, content, footer. all floating left. then inside content put all your <main> stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the footer:

```
position: absolute;
```

That will display it on the bottom of the browser. If you would like it below #main, give footer:

```
top: 1600px;
```

Comment: imagine another page where main section has height more or less than on this page. What then? You have to set top value for every page. This is simplest solution, but not right